# Каким образом не скрывать меню при наведении

Tags: html, css

Есть всплывающее меню, которое появляется при наведении, и пропадает сразу после смещения курсора с его области.
Каким образом не скрывать это меню, если курсор сместился в область его под-меню?

```css
.wow_order {
  display: none;
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.wow_order a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
}

a.wow_wow:hover ~ .wow_order {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="wow_wow" href="javascript:;">Мебель</a>
<div class="wow_order">
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Kuhni-na-zakaz">Кухни</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/SHkafy-na-zakaz">Шкафы</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Detskie-komnaty">Детские комнаты</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Ofisnaja-mebel-na-zakaz">Офисная мебель</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Prihozhie-na-zakaz">Прихожие</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Vannye-komnaty">Ванные комнаты</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавить наведение и на само меню `.wow_order:hover`:

```css
.wow_order {
  display: none;
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.wow_order a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
}

a.wow_wow:hover ~ .wow_order,
.wow_order:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="wow_wow" href="javascript:;">Мебель</a>
<div class="wow_order">
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Kuhni-na-zakaz">Кухни</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/SHkafy-na-zakaz">Шкафы</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Detskie-komnaty">Детские комнаты</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Ofisnaja-mebel-na-zakaz">Офисная мебель</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Prihozhie-na-zakaz">Прихожие</a>
 <a href="/proekti-na-zakaz/Vannye-komnaty">Ванные комнаты</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Лена ты  здесь ?